# flink systemctl faild to start

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

Hi i want to create systemctl service to tun flink local server .

I can run it directly from the **/bin/start-local.sh**

But when im using this service definition .

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Flink
Documentation=http://flink.apache.org/
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=beam1
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
ExecStart=/opt/flink-1.3.2/bin/start-local.sh
ExecStop=-/opt/flink-1.3.2/bin/stop-local.sh
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Im getting an error , what`s wrong in my service defenition ?

```
Oct 17 04:41:57 beam1 stop-local.sh[3997]: No jobmanager daemon (pid: 3995) is running anymore on beam1.
Oct 17 04:41:57 beam1 systemd[1]: flink.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 17 04:41:57 beam1 systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Flink.
Oct 17 04:41:57 beam1 systemd[1]: Started Apache Flink.
Oct 17 04:41:57 beam1 start-local.sh[4411]: Starting jobmanager daemon on host beam1.
Oct 17 04:41:57 beam1 stop-local.sh[4817]: No jobmanager daemon (pid: 4814) is running anymore on beam1.
Oct 17 04:41:58 beam1 systemd[1]: flink.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 17 04:41:58 beam1 systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Flink.
Oct 17 04:41:58 beam1 systemd[1]: flink.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 17 04:41:58 beam1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Flink.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Use other type :)

```
Type=forking
```

systemd [man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) page says:

> If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with
> ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent
> process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all
> communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the
> main service process, and the service manager will consider the unit
> started when the parent process exits. This is the behavior of
> traditional UNIX services. If this setting is used, it is recommended
> to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can reliably identify
> the main process of the service. systemd will proceed with starting
> follow-up units as soon as the parent process exits.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Perhaps you could add an explanation on _why_ this would solve the OPs problem, and how you deduced that this was the right solution. That way, people who google for this problem will not only know how to solve it, but also why it happened and how to avoid it in the future ...